# Ethereum mainnet to Polygon State Sync Fails to callback on Child (Polygon) side

Tags: ethereum, solidity, polygon-pos

I'm having an issue with the custom State Sync mechanism, as described in Polygon docs here: https://docs.polygon.technology/docs/develop/l1-l2-communication/state-transfer.

I'm just trying to send a message from mainnet to polygon.

I've deployed these two contracts on the root and child side. I am able to call the root side with:

```
_sendMessageToChild(message)
```

but nothing makes it to the child side in:

```
function _processMessageFromRoot(
    uint256 stateId,
    address sender,
    bytes memory data
) internal override validateSender(sender) {
```

Is there something I'm missing? Do I need to register these contracts somewhere? Do I need to pay gas for it to land on the Polygon side?

https://polygonscan.com/address/0xbF54174d00Ab9aC639091dCeE58D814302a866e0#readContract

https://etherscan.io/address/0xbF54174d00Ab9aC639091dCeE58D814302a866e0